# Getting Blank Array on First Click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I am stuck with a Reactjs problem. The problem is mentioned in App.js file. Please look into [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-joliot-0sxdq?file=/src/components/Game.js). Initially all buttons are White and not clickable, how can I change there color after some time. Should I use `useEffect` hook or some other way. I am not getting the index of button randomly to change their color and `isDisable`.

Three Type of Button

1. White: initially all buttons are white and not clickable.
2. Red: Randomly from the white button, One button will be red and clickable.
3. Blue: Clicked Button. After clicking on the red button color will change to blue and not clickable.

When all white buttons become blue, give custom popup in the center of the screen with the icon "You won game…!!!"

I am trying below code to change button color randomly, but fails.

```
const changeColorHandle = () => {
    const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
    btnArray.map((i, k) => {
      if (i.index === rand) {
        return ([...btnArray, { color: 'red', isDisable: false }])
      }
      return [...btnArray]
    })
    console.log(rand)
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (btnArray.length > 0) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        changeColorHandle()
      }, 2000);
    }
  }, [btnArray])
```

Can anybody please solve this problem [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-joliot-0sxdq?file=/src/components/Game.js). And show me where I am doing it wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: You set your `buttonValue` too late, thus it always is one click behind.

Comment: Can you please tell where should I set this.?

Comment: @JavaScript buttonValue is set to onChange input box. and when I click to Enter button it set to buttonCount.

Comment: **Moderator Note** - Please do not overwrite a particular question that you have asked with a completely different and unrelated question. [Ask a new question instead.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Answer (score 1):

One thing you don't want to really mess with the new react hooks is that they are not really applying changes synchronously, that way sometimes you can have a little delay.

I don't think it's the issue here but you can have a more efficient code that also solve the problem :)

Code Sandbox is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-firefly-0mf78)

Raw snippet with lines changed is here:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Button from "./Button";

const Game = () => {
  const [buttonValue, setButtonValue] = useState(0);
  const [btnArray, setBtnArray] = useState([]);

  const handleChange = e => {
    setButtonValue(parseInt(e.target.value, 10));
  };

  const onClickHandle = () => {
    const tmpArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < buttonValue; i++) {
      tmpArray.push({ color: "white", isDisable: true });
    }
    setBtnArray(tmpArray);
  };

  const changeColorHandle = () => {
    alert("clicked");
  };
  
  (rest is ok )
```

So as you can see, `buttonValue` is **removed**, and the job of the `onClick` is just to generate a new array according to the actual value of the input.

You don't get any issue with the user playing with the input value as the `btnArray` will only be rendered once he has clicked the button :)
(rendering triggered by the state change done with `setBtnArray()`

Edit: One nice sweet addition could be getting rid of `buttonValue` as a string as you may use math operations on it rather than using string conversion back and forth

Comment: You've completely changed the original post, you should have created an other one ^^'

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out your issue, you are setting the button count after clicking so it is running one step behind the array values, and button color change function is also added, check this: CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-ganguly-e805g?file=/src/components/Game.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Button from "./Button";

const Game = () => {
  const [buttonValue, setButtonValue] = useState("");
  const [buttonCount, setButtonCount] = useState(0);
  const [btnArray, setBtnArray] = useState([]);

  const handleChange = e => {
    //you are not using button value any where
    //setButtonValue(e.target.value);
    setButtonCount(parseInt(e.target.value, 10));
  };

  const onClickHandle = () => {
    if (btnArray.length > 0) {
      setBtnArray([]);
    }
    // setButtonCount(parseInt(buttonValue, 10)); //actually you were setting the count very late so it is one step behind
    setButtonValue("");
    console.log(buttonCount);
    let tempArr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < buttonCount; i++) {
      tempArr.push({ index: i, color: "white", isDisable: false });
      setBtnArray(tempArr);
    }
    console.log(btnArray);
  };

  const changeColorHandle = btnIndex => {
    console.log(btnIndex);

    //change that button color and save btn array again
    let newBtnArray = btnArray.map(btn => {
      if (btn.index === btnIndex) {
        btn["color"] = "blue";
      } else {
        //else change all buttons color back to white
        btn["color"] = "white";
      }
      return btn;
    });
    setBtnArray(newBtnArray); // set new array with modified colors
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col">
            <input type="text" onChange={handleChange} />
            <button onClick={onClickHandle}>Enter</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br />

        <div className="row">
          {btnArray.map((i, k) => (
            <Button
              key={k}
              color={i.color}
              isDisable={i.isDisable}
              onClick={() => changeColorHandle(i.index)}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Game;
```

Comment: then you have to save index as well : `btnArray.push({ index:i, color: "white", isDisable: true });`

Comment: i have updated the answer, check now, if its helpful then vote it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you're setting multiple states very quickly in succession. By the time you get to your loop, your buttonCount state is behind and thus the loop where you're pushing values onto btnArray doesn't really run (ends immediately).

Quick aside: You're attempting to mutate btnArray directly inside the loop, don't do that if possible. Create a new Array, push values onto that and then setBtnArray to the new Array.

This works:

```
const onClickHandle = () => {
if (btnArray.length > 0) {
  setBtnArray([]);
}
let newBtnArray = [];
for (let i = 0; i < parseInt(buttonValue, 10); i++) {
  newBtnArray.push({ color: "blue", isDisable: true });
}
setBtnArray(newBtnArray); };
```

I threw out btnCount here, but if you need it for something else, you can set it seperately.